# How to fecth filename only (without content) on GIT

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I try to use FILTER option for git when I fetch/pull/clone repository. I only want file list without file content.

Where should filter be placed ? Within the want line ? Or (like deepen) on a new line ?
How should I chain filter and filter's option ? Like with the command line version filter=filter'sOption OR filter filter'sOption ?

Any successful usage of filter option in an HTTP POST resquest to GIT (GITHUB) is welcome.
Thanks in advance as documentation is not clear at all on this particular topic.

I've tried with several filter option :

- filter=blob:none
- filter=blob:limit=[kmg]

Without any success, either I no longer get any thing or results are unchanged (file + content).
Note: what ever limit I've set 5 byte to 512Mb

I've try to post this kind of body :

```
0056want 0210b0aa4666d7727cd8da894e15ffbc53dc18d0 side-band-64k no-progress multi_ack
000Ddeepen 1
0016filter=:limit=512
00000009done
```

OR

```
006Awant 0210b0aa4666d7727cd8da894e15ffbc53dc18d0 side-band-64k no-progress multi_ack filter=blob:limit=5
000Ddeepen 1
00000009done
```

I expect file lis without filecontent to save network bandwidth

Comment: Please share the actual calls you are using.

Comment: If your question is actually about a repo hosted on GitHub or git lab, you may also look into the API to those services.

Comment: I've share my calls :
POST
With
006Awant 0210b0aa4666d7727cd8da894e15ffbc53dc18d0 side-band-64k no-progress multi_ack filter=blob:limit=5
000Ddeepen 1
00000009done

Comment: I do not want to use GITHUB or GITLAB dedicated API I want to stay compatible with Git (only)
I expect that the filter option allow to split the fetch into several pieces or at lest to save network bandwidth... or avoid HTTP 500